# Outputting a relationship field inside a grid field

Tags: relationships, conditionals, grid, related-entries

So I have a grid field with two columns, one of which is a Wygwam field, the other a relationship field. I want to list all the rows in the grid, outputting the Wygwam field as the text, and surrounding it in a link to the relationship field only if a related entry has been selected. Not all rows will have related entries selected. Something like this:

```
<ol>
    {my-grid-field}
        <li>
            {my-grid-field:my-relationship-field}
                {if '{my-grid-field:my-relationship-field:total_results}' > '0'}
                    <a href="{path='template-group/template/{my-grid-field:my-relationship-field:url_title}'}">{my-grid-field:my-wygwam-field}</a>
                {if:else}
                    {my-grid-field:my-wygwam-field}
                {/if}
            {/my-grid-field:my-relationship-field}
        </li>
    {/my-grid-field}
</ol>
```

That code outputs a numbered list but only displays items where the conditional is true. The other items are blank. So if the first and fifth items have related entries, the list looks like this:

```
1 [Wygwam field with correct link around it]
2
3
4
5 [Wygwam field with correct link around it]
```

Comment: Are you getting any output at all? What happens if you try without the conditional? Have you tried this code in a blank template?

Comment: I see your update, how about trying two simple conditionals instead - see my pastie http://pastie.org/9595127

Comment: Nope. Same result.
I did notice that I can add the Wygwam field *outside* of the relationship loop and make them all show up that way. So instead of wrapping the text in a link when there's a related entry, I could create a button that links to the related entry and place that beside the Wygwam text. Acceptable workaround I guess.

Comment: Mike - if you want the link to work the way you originally wanted you might consider using Stash or MX Jumper to get the wygwam field content and then drop it inside of the link tags.

Comment: Yeah, I considered Stash. I'll keep that in mind.